# Are there words for "second cousin twice removed" in other languages?

Tags: english, cross-linguistic, kinship-terms

I know in english we have a whole bunch of terms like this, do other languages have something similar?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/second_cousin#Translations, https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/first_cousin_once_removed#Translations ...